# Prove continuous function attains its $\limsup$ and $\liminf$

Tags: analysis, continuity

I am trying to prove that if a function, say $f$, is continuous, then given its $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are not equal, they should be attended by the function at some points.

Informally it should be quite obvious because we can look at a closed interval $[a,b]$ at some neighbourhood of infinity so that $b$ would not be equal $\limsup$ (otherwise $\liminf$ will not appear) and then by the Cauchy theorem there will be a point $x$ where $f(x)$ is equal it's $\limsup$.

Could you help me to compose a formally correct proof?
Thank you all!

Comment: Sorry, I should've be more concrete about the function.
Let's say it bounded on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)=(1-e^{-x})\sin x$$
which is continuous and bounded on $[0,\infty)$. Its supremum and infinum
are $\pm1$ but the function never attains them.

You really need compactness of the domain to ensure attainment of suprema/infima.

Comment: Thank you, I will be more accurate with my intuition!